# Check if a list is defined and avoid the "UNDEFINED" error

Tags: list, ti-basic

In the original TI-BASIC (for TI-83/84+) is there a way to check if a list has been defined?

Currently calling `dim(⌊LIST)` will return an error if the list is not defined.

[image]

Is there a way to handle that error gracefully?

**Possible Workaround:**
The only hacky way I can think of doing so is to redefine the list with more items than you're expecting such as `99→dim(⌊LIST)` and check if the first few values are not zero. But that seems wasteful and slow.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need this to tell you whether the list previously existed, or is any way to avoid that error OK?

Comment: @harold Well imagine a game with high scores saved into a list. On first run it needs to check whether the list exists. I suppose it could just define the list to have X items which will fill any missing elements with zeroes, but in some cases you don’t exactly know how many items you’ll need and declaring something overly large like 50 seems like a waste of memory. If you declare it too small it will truncate the remaining items and they’ll be lost. Not ideal either.

Comment: Perhaps the [`SetUpEditor` command](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/setupeditor) is suitable for what you want

Comment: Thanks @harold - wow, great tip! Yes, that sounds like the best workaround so far. Since you didn't post an answer, I've added the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a clean, simple function for checking if a list already exists, but thanks to harold who posted this as a comment, there is a workaround:

The [`SetUpEditor` command](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/setupeditor).

This is typically used for specifying which lists are displayed in the list editor, but the command has the side-effect of creating a zero-length list if it does not exist yet.

So here's some sample code, with comments:

```
"Create two empty lists if they do not exist yet
SetUpEditor FOO,BAR

"Check the size of FOO
dim(∟FOO)→X

"Clean up by returning the list editor back to
"its default state (∟1-∟6)
SetUpEditor
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have control during the lists's creation, then another workaround would be to use another list with only one element (or a list of another fixed size, or a letter variable) as a flag that indicates this main list exists.

Something like this, for lists LMAIN and LFLAG:

```
1->dim(LFLAG
If 5784923472≠LFLAG(1
Then
"assume LMAIN does not exist because flag hasn't been set
"insert optional other code here
0->dim(LMAIN
5784923472->LFLAG(1
End
```

Comment: Thanks Quaris. I suppose that's not a bad workaround. The only issue that could be hit is if the user archives or deletes `LMAIN` but leaves `LFLAG` in place. Then you'll still hit an error. But that's reasonably unlikely... well, unless `LMAIN` is quite large and the user is trying to recover space on their device.